# Why won't rails recognize this route? (What Am I Doing Wrong? Making a Click Counter)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm making a "click counter", i.e, when a user clicks a button, we want to count the clicks. In my case, the user is visiting a page for coupons, and I want to count the number of time she clicks the print button.

To set this up, I created a "click" model.

```
class Click < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :coupon
end
```

And a click controller with a create method.

```
class ClicksController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @coupon = Coupon.find(params[:id])
    @coupon.clicks.create

    respond_to do |format| 
        format.html { redirect_to @coupon }
    end
  end
end
```

And I've created a migration like this:

```
class CreateClicks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :clicks do |t|
      t.integer :coupon_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :clicks
  end
end
```

Then I configure my routes like so:

```
map.resources :coupons, :has_many => :clicks

map.resources :clicks
map.connect 'coupons/:id/clicks', :controller => 'clicks', :action => 'create'
```

And then the button that ads 1 click:

```
<%form_remote_tag :url => coupon_clicks_path(@coupon) do %>
<% submit_tag 'click!' %>
<% end %>
```

Then I browse to /coupons/4/clicks .... and it gives me an error saying that it can't find the page. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the actual error in it's entirety. There are a couple of things that could be happening.

Comment: I didn't even know you could do a has_many in the routes, I thought it was just a model thing.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention this is all Rails 2. (I didn't write the project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Matthew mentioned it looks like you're using Rails 2, the reason your route isn't recognized is that you're defining it after the resources of coupons. They both share the part of the route '/coupons' so that resource's REST routes are overriding `'coupons/:id/clicks'`.

As is says in the routes.rb default comments: The priority is based upon order of creation, first created -> highest priority.

So to get your `'coupons/:id/clicks'` route to of a higher priority move it to the top of the routes.rb file.

Answer (score 0):

First off it would be interesting to know what version of rails you are using because some of this stuff looks like rails 2 but rails 3 has been out for years now. Also, I'm not sure why you want to set this up as an association when click count could just be an attribute of your model, but there are couple things I see wrong here:

First make sure your coupon model has implemented it's side of the association:

```
class  Coupon< ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :click
end
```

Also the way you are trying to configure your routes is old school. Try this:

```
resources :coupons do
    resources :clicks
end
```

Then change your form tag so its this:

```
<%= form_tag( coupon_clicks_path(@coupon) ) %>
```

Or this if you really want to do it via ajax:

```
<%= form_tag(coupon_clicks_path(@coupon), :remote => true) %>
```

Comment: Coupon would have_many clicks, though. But anyway overall you're right click count should just be an attribute, I don't know why i decided to do this way... Thanks for your feedback!